# interpolate velocity for a curved mesh

Tags: matlab

'x','y' and 'u' are 2D matrices for the x-coordinate, y-coordinate, and velocity of each node of the below mesh (figure). and I want to interpolate for (x_q,y_q) to find u_q for an arbitrary point(q).

My mesh is not rectangular and "interp2" error is: "Input grid is not a valid MESHGRID".

Any Ideal what can I do?

Thanks.

[image]

minimal reproducible example:

```
x=[0.0482114583977891,0.0482201588072998,0.0482288592168105;0.0513027685854806,0.0512573490659834,0.0512119412024664;0.0550957532853860,0.0550195888619688,0.0549437786953572;0.0589706773586289,0.0589051888951395,0.0588397004316502];
y=[-0.0481475644832381,-0.0450026617243515,-0.0418577589654650;-0.0454644879533678,-0.0426002662557475,-0.0397360636257961;-0.0434988768053532,-0.0408400599208391,-0.0381819554721181;-0.0414343539900984,-0.0389341351227583,-0.0364339162554183];
u=[1.52583130467469,14.3816671073665,58.5433654462735;108.677373003789,124.842139940676,145.468567077514;110.206733380171,111.157308056414,111.709609403516;135.414711548714,138.843419308648,147.988201447309];
xq=0.065;
yq=0.035;
uq = interp2(x,y,u,xq,yq,'cubic',0);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. You've shown a 2D mesh but described a 3D mesh, so it's unclear how the interpolation is defined

Comment: you are right. I tried to create a  minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

The `interp2` function needs a regular grid (for instance something that was createed by `meshgrid`). In your case you have scattered data, in which case it you'd have to use [`griddata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) for interpolation:

```
uq = griddata(x,y,u,xq,yq, 'nearest');
```

(Note that in your MCVE your query point is way outside of the defined input points, so only `'nearest'` will really work as a method.)

Answer (score 1):

Per Matlab documentation for the `interp2` function, the requirements for cubic spline interpolation are:

> - Grid must have uniform spacing in each dimension, but the spacing does not have to be the same for all dimensions
> - Requires at least four points in each dimension

In the case of your code, neither of these conditions is met.

You would need to make sure that the x and y points are evenly spaced, ideally using `meshgrid` to generate the points and you would need to make the specified points, which are currently 3x4, at least 4x4.

Documentation for the function is found here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html

There is a response to a similar question here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/866695-input-grid-is-not-a-valid-meshgrid